# What is translated?

Tags: cryptic-crosswords, printers-devilry

[image]

**Note**: Six of the clues are **printer's devilry** with thematic answers.

**Across**
1. Grandson to Isaac Newton, son to filmmaker Barry (8)
5. Selling a product of ale? Sue for a higher price (6)
9. Sport follower entertained by an awfully tired racing driver (8)
10. Showered, readin' comic (6)
11. Particle destroying a cat (3)
12. You and Lizzy running to get opening frame in football club, which is not an exact science (5,5)
14. First, um, is a pleasant savoury taste (4)
16. Perhaps used to being thrown out (6)
19. Gal ioned his detractors (7)
22. New luxury IP hates ruler, purchased (7)
23. Freezing street in its present condition (6)
27. After the wart, hear my bat: Tai's broken up (4)
28. Representative of Maradona accidentally having both feet cut, sliced by singer (10)
31. A degree of affliction eradicated in Swazi capital (3, abbr.)
32. Group of 25 down – what is translated from Italian to Spanish? (6)
33. Having gotten intravenous injection, tell others the ending to *White Noise* (8)
34. Prominent Marxist's unfinished legend about the entrance of Soviets (6)
35. Visitors of "Exodus" author being surrounded by small children (8)

**Down**
1. Prof. Gale breaking up children's game (8)
2. Five jazz insiders holding you in Germany's capital (5)
3. Poor trainee, dying in secret (5)
4. No point being spoilt for choice (6)
6. Some preferred American cheese (4)
7. Headless 18 down protects leading groups (9)
8. Grotesque – Daily News' primary typeface (6)
10. Massive flyer for Republic of China's leaders (3)
11. An English Tex man is Ed (5)
13. Spot components of Nazi tanks (3)
15. Use plant regularly, leading to altercation (4)
17. Secretly following doing wash up (9)
18. A man's electric car (4)
20. Bogey man seen near a city in Italy (5)
21. Illegitimate rulers initially under pressure, perhaps losing backer (8)
24. Ignore men, Lady Lovelace (3)
25. Overused trope: an undead creature in ice, without its head (6)
26. Language perceived at first as hot mess (6)
28. Lincoln, Nebraska beheaded prisoners (3)
29. Cut grass back at any time (5)
30. Day of defeat's beginning for Islamic State, missing top fighter (5)
31. Think about cliff in Scotland (4)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Grid:

> [image]

The p.d. answers are all

> felids.

Wordplay explanations:

> **Across**:
>  1a. LEVI (grandson of biblical patriarch Isaac) + N + SON.
>  5a. pd. "...of a lesser value for...".
>  9a. (-spor)T in AN TIRED*.
>  10a. READIN*.
>  11a. ATOM minus A.
>  12a. ULIZZY* + O(-penin)G in FC.
>  14a. pd. "First up, umami's...".
>  16a. USEDTO*.
>  19a. pd. "Galileo pardoned...".
>  22a. pd. "New luxury car a Caliphate's...".
>  23a. ST AS IS.
>  26a. P AS HOT*.
>  27a. pd. "After the war, the army battalion...".
>  28a. MARADO(-na)* sliced by BASS.
>  31a. MBABANE minus BANE.
>  32a. CLICHE with CHE -> QUE.
>  33a. IV in SHARE + (-whit)E.
>  34a. LEGEN(-d)* around S.
>  35a. URIS surrounded by TOTS.
>  **Down**:
>  1d. PROFGALE*.
>  2d. V + (-a)AZ(-z) containing DU.
>  3d. Substring.
>  4d. O + POINT*.
>  6d. Substring.
>  7d. (-e)VAN + GUARDS.
>  8d. DAILY* + N(-ews).
>  10d. R() O() C().
>  11d. pd. "An English text I Germanized", I guess?
>  13d. Substring.
>  15d. (-u)S(-e)P(-l)A(-n)T.
>  17d. DOINGWASH*.
>  18d. E+VAN. (Is a VAN really a CAR?)
>  20d. PAR + M + A. But bogey is *one over* par, isn't it?
>  21d. U + PRESSUR(-e)*.
>  24d. MADAM without its Ms.
>  25d. LICH in (-i)CE.
>  28d. Substring.
>  29d. (-gras)S + EVER.
>  30d. D(-efeat) + (-f)OR IS.
>  31d. Double def.

Comment: Oops, forgot to actually enter one answer in the grid. Will fix. [EDITED to add:] Now done.

Comment: Re: 20d, I though they're synonyms in [this sense](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Par_(golf_scoring_format)), but maybe I've misunderstood? I'm not familiar with that game at all.

Comment: Huh. I hadn't known that the rot13(fpbevat flfgrz) was known by both those names. Today I learned something. (Actually, two things; I hadn't known rot13(FUVINERR), which I guessed on the basis of rot13("punevinev") which I did know.)

Answer (score 4):

Grid:

> [image: IM]

The printer's devilry theme is:

> cats: lion, tiger, serval, caracal, puma, leopard

1 Grandson to Isaac Newton, son to filmmaker Barry (8)

> lev + in + son??

5 Selling a product of ale? Sue for a higher price (6)

> pd:    selling a product of a les**ser val**ue for a higher price

9 Sport follower entertained by an awfully tired racing driver (8)

> (spor)'T'  contained by  'an' and 'tired' anagram

10 Showered, readin' comic (6)

> 'readin' anagram

11 Particle destroying a cat (3)

> 'atom' without 'a'

12 You and Lizzy running to get opening frame in football club, which is not an exact science (5,5)

> F.C. surrounding  'u' and 'lizzy' anagram with 'og'????

14 First, um, is a pleasant savoury taste (4)

> pd:   first u**p, uma**mi's a pleasant savoury taste

16 Perhaps used to being thrown out (6)

> 'used to' anagram

19 Gal ioned his detractors (7)

> pd:    gali**leo pard**oned his detractors.

22 New luxury IP hates ruler, purchased (7)

> pd: New luxury **car a cal**iphates ruler purchased

23 Freezing street in its present condition (6)

> st. + as-is

27 After the wart, hear my bat: Tai's broken up (4)

> pd:  After the war, the army batta**lion** is broken up

28 Representative of Maradona accidentally having both feet cut, sliced by singer (10)

> 'marado'(na) anagrammed containing 'bass'

31 A degree of affliction eradicated in Swazi capital (3, abbr.)

> 'mbabane' - 'bane'

32 Group of 25 down – what is translated from Italian to Spanish? (6)

> 'cliche', with che -> que

33 Having gotten intravenous injection, tell others the ending to White Noise (8)

> 'share' containing IV, with (whit)E

34 Prominent Marxist's unfinished legend about the entrance of Soviets (6)

> 'legen' anagrammed  + 's'oviets

35 Visitors of "Exodus" author being surrounded by small children (8)

> 'tots' surrounding 'uris'

1 Prof. Gale breaking up children's game (8)

> anagram of 'prof gale'

2 Five jazz insiders holding you in Germany's capital (5)

> fiVe  and jaZz containing 'uda'???

3 Poor trainee, dying in secret (5)

> hidden:   traiNEE DYing

4 No point being spoilt for choice (6)

> o (none) + 'point' anagrammed

6 Some preferred American cheese (4)

> hidden:  preferrED AMerican

7 Headless 18 down protects leading group (9)

> (e)'VAN' + 'guards'

8 Grotesque – Daily News' primary typeface (6)

> 'daily' anagrammed + 'N'(ews)

10 Massive flyer for Republic of China's leaders (3)

> initials of 'Republic Of China'

11 An English Tex man is Ed (5)

> pd:   an English tex**t I ger**manised

13 Spot components of Nazi tanks (3)

> hidden:   naZI Tanks

15 Use plant regularly, leading to altercation (4)

> take every other letter from 'use plant'

17 Secretly following doing wash up (9)

> 'doing wash' anagram

18 A man's electric car (4)

> 'e' + 'van'

20 Bogey man seen near a city in Italy (5)

> bogey -> 'par' + 'm' + 'a'

21 Illegitimate rulers initially under pressure, perhaps losing backer (8)

> 'U'(nder) + 'PRESSUR'(e)   anagrammed

24 Ignore men, Lady Lovelace (3)

> ?????    Lady Lovelace = Ada

25 Overused trope: an undead creature in ice, without its head (6)

> ????

26 Language perceived at first as hot mess (6)

> 'P'(erceived) + 'ashot' anagrammed

28 Lincoln, Nebraska beheaded prisoners (3)

> hidden: nebraskA BEheaded

29 Cut grass back at any time (5)

> (gras)'S' + 'ever'

30 Day of defeat's beginning for Islamic State, missing top fighter (5)

> ????

31 Think about cliff in Scotland (4)

> double definition

Comment: I feel like I've solved enough to warrant an answer. If that's not the case, feel free to tell me.

Comment: I'm (I think) a couple of minutes away from a complete independent solution. [EDITED to add:] Of course I haven't looked at your answers, and won't until I'm done or have given up.

Comment: Oops, didn't notice there was an error in 7 down until now (should be "groups", not "group"). Sorry about that!

Comment: You're only missing one clue, right? 39 down. Definitely enough to warrant an answer :-)

Comment: @Randal'Thor - I don't have some of the full explanations, tho.

Comment: Ah, but I do :-).

Comment: Yes, I figured that based on your earlier comment.

Comment: Now that I'm allowed to look: you definitely did have a couple of them before I did.

Comment: @jafe - It is not clear to me that 34a includes an anagram word.

Comment: @LannyStrack Isn't "about" a valid one?

Comment: @jafe - Sorry, my mistake.

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan - I still don't know all the protocol on this site, but...  I don't know what you meant by your comment "you definitely did have a couple of them before I did", but if that means you changed any explanations after viewing my answers, I'd appreciate a credit being added on the relevant lines. As for my own solution, there are six clues I did not have the proper explanations for, all of which I have now learned from your post. I am leaving my solution unaltered for now, though.

Comment: I absolutely did not change anything of mine on the basis of anything of yours; I didn't look at any of your answers until I had finished mine. I just meant that, given when you posted your answer and when I did what, there are some clues that you solved before I did.

Comment: Cheers, mate...